# Polynomial addition using python

Tags: python, math

Suppose a polynomial, P_A(x, 5) = x^5 + 2x^4 + 8x^2 + 9x^1 + 3, can be decomposed into two lists, exp = [5,4,2,1,0] and coeff = [1,2,8,9,0].

I'd like to write a function that can take four lists as inputs, for example: add_coefficient(exp1, coeff1, exp2, coeff2) and returns a list of coefficients in the order respect to the corresponding exponents, which is just a sorted set of exp1 and exp2. How can I implement this? I'm thinking of collections.counter() or while loops, but can't get started.

Comment: General tips or starting help are off-topic. We mostly deal with problems emerging from code you have already written. Please read the Asking section of the [help].

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: i think coeff = [1,2,8,9,0] -> would be coeff = [1,2,8,9,3]  but  i dont understant what you want... difficult to understant your explanations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably more computationally efficient ways of doing it, but I'd iterate through each list storing the results in a dictionary, which seems to me to be the natural way to handle this relationship in Python.

```
exp_1 = [5,3,2,4] 
coeff_1 = [1,1,1,1]
exp_2 = [5,3,2,1] 
coeff_2 = [1,1,1,1]

def add_coefficient(exp1, coeff1, exp2, coeff2):
    exponent_coefficient_dict = dict()
    # Iterate through first pair of lists, storing as exp:coeff pairs.
    for index, exponent in enumerate(exp1):
        exponent_coefficient_dict[exponent] = coeff1[index]
    # Iterate through second pair of lists, storing or updating pairs.
    for index, exponent in enumerate(exp2):
        exponent_coefficient_dict[exponent] = exponent_coefficient_dict.get(exponent, 0) + coeff2[index]

    # Get a sorted list of the keys from the dictionary.
    combined_exp_list = sorted(exponent_coefficient_dict, reverse=True)
    combined_coeff_list = []

    # Populate a list for the coefficients according to the order 
    # the exponents appear in.
    for exponent in combined_exp_list:
        combined_coeff_list.append(exponent_coefficient_dict.get(exponent, 0))

    return (combined_exp_list, combined_coeff_list)

add_coefficient(exp_1, coeff_1, exp_2, coeff_2)
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution works for other cases! Kudos for understanding my rather vague (according to others who commented) problem statement. For a noob even attempting a starter code sometimes is blocked, and I don't think people are too keen on seeing that in SO